# How I make OSX never open apps automatically when I connect any hardware?

Tags: osx-el-capitan

Every time I connect any device, OSX opens whatever app it thinks is appropriate to handle the device (like iTunes, Photos, Image Capture, and so on).

This is becoming rage inducing to me, of the sort I want to punch something, because I am a dev with lots of test devices, and one of my cables is damaged and the device on it keeps reconnecting, and the computer slowns down a lot when an app opens, AND it steals focus.

So how I make so that it never happens again?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I managed to kill the behaviour with a combination of these two methods...

For common devices...

- Connect device.
- Launch Image Capture [in Applications]
- Set "Connecting this iPhone opens:" - No application

[image]

For 'one-off' devices...

- Install [RCDefaultApp](http://www.rubicode.com/Software/RCDefaultApp/index.html) which is old but still works in El Capitan
- In the Media tab I have simply set all options to 'Ignore' - even though there is no option for USB cards, they don't launch anything either now.

[image]

Comment: This didn't worked :( Some devices still auto-open programs.

Comment: For iPhones/iPads etc, you need to set each one's behaviour in Image Capture, there's no way round that. Mine definitely doesn't launch anything for USB sticks/SD cards any more.

Comment: One iPod stopped doing it for a while, but now started doing it again.

Comment: Then it's forgotten, for some reason, just set it again

Comment: I am accepting this because is the closest... I never found out a solution, seemly it can't be done. Shame on you Apple.